# Pass an argument to anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

i try to undestand the scope of this wrapped function.

```
  componentWillMount = () => {
    //-----------------------
    // props accesible here:
    //-----------------------
    console.log(this.props);
    $(function() {
      var jqconsole = $('#console').jqconsole('Welcome to the console!\n', '>');
      jqconsole.Write(
        //-----------------------
        // props inaccesible here:
        //-----------------------
        this.getMessagesFromJavascriptWindow(this.props.code) + '\n',
        'jqconsole-output'
      );
      var startPrompt = function() {
        // Start the prompt with history enabled.
        jqconsole.Prompt(true, function(input) {
          let transformedString;
          try {
            transformedString = eval(input);
            // Output input with the class jqconsole-output.
            jqconsole.Write(transformedString + '\n', 'jqconsole-output');
            // Restart the input prompt.
            startPrompt();
          } catch (error) {
            jqconsole.Write(error + '\n', 'jqconsole-output-error');
            // Restart the input prompt.
            startPrompt();
          }
        });
      };
      // Restart the input prompt.
      startPrompt();
    });
  };
```

I am new to JQuery. I need to pass an argument to this anonymous function while using the JQuery wrapper. 
Can somebody explain this or show me corresponding docs? I did not find it.

edit:

For some context: What i am doing is happening in a React components `componentWillMount` method. And i am trying to access the props.

Comment: *"test is not accessible here"* - You sure about that?  https://jsfiddle.net/65j82he3

Comment: i made some edits @David

Comment: it is accessible. const test = 5;

$(function(){ console.log(test);});

Comment: my edits are really bad so sorry

Comment: @Spacemoose: Can you provide a *complete* and *demonstrable* example of the problem?  What is `this`?  What is `props`?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: why is everyone so hasty with the downvotes and closing? Sad. I ll do my best to update my post accordingly in a sec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the context where you call your function knows of test, otherwise you obviously will not be able to pass something you don't know.

Then proceed like this:

```
var self = this;
$(function( self ){ can access this.props here via self.props })
```

You can always pass parameters to anonymous functions, but the context where you call them needs to know about these parameters. This is also how deferred works:

```
/** define in some context */
var dfd = $.Deferred();
dfd.resolve( 5 );

/** define in some other context, that knows of the dfd above */
dfd.done( function ( param ) { console.log( param ); });

// result: 5
```

With respect to your edit:

```
var self = this; // before calling the anonymous function
```

Then use

```
self.props
```

in the anonymous function.

EDIT: I think in your case you don't even need to pass any parameters. All you need is to take care of `this`. When in doubt, save a context to a variable.

Comment: I updated my post with the complete code example FYI.

Comment: To extend: The `dfd.resolve( 5 );` may even be called again in some third context, the anonymous function will still have received `5` as input parameter. This deferred example is a demonstration of anonymous functoion usage, so you see how parameters can be passed to different functions in different contexts.

Comment: Thank you for the effort. I ll read this and see if i understand.

Comment: I added some addendum after replicating your updated problem, see `EDIT` in my post.